# Why does asyncio.sleep(0) make my code faster?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

If I delete this line from my scanner,

```
await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Work time grows from 5s to 400s.

Why is this happening?

My code:

```
import os
import asyncio
import time

async def rl(response):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return response.readlines()  

async def scan_Ip(addr):
    print(addr)
    response = os.popen("ping -n 1 " + addr)
    data = await rl(response)
    for line in data:
        if 'TTL' in line:
            print(data)

async def scan():
    tasks=[]
    for ip in range(0, 256):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(scan_Ip(f'192.168.8.{ip}')))
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    asyncio.run(scan())
    print(f"--- {time.time() - start_time} seconds ---")
```

Comment: I'm going to go on a limb here and guess it has something to do with `os` not being adapted to work with async and the sleep forcing a context switch which lets you queue up all the jobs, but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 20):

As pointed out by Nullman in a comment on the question, `os.popen` doesn't provide an async interface, so using it from asyncio makes the coroutine that does so block the event loop. A consequence of that is that multiple such coroutines execute sequentially regardless of the use of `gather` or `wait`.

Notice how your `rl` function reads data with a blocking `readlines()` call and doesn't actually await anything (other than `sleep(0)`). That is a reliable indicator that `rl` is not async except in name and that it will cause a bottleneck once you try to run it in parallel.

The correct way to interface with `ping` from asyncio is using the asyncio equivalent of `os.popen`:

```
async def scan_Ip(addr):
    print(addr)
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "ping", "-n", "1", addr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    async for line in proc.stdout:
        if 'TTL' in line:
            print(data)
```

Now process interaction is performed with async calls, which allows performing them in parallel for all 256 processes.

As for why `await asyncio.sleep(0)` helps - awaiting `asyncio.sleep()` forces the async function to yield control to the event loop ([even when the delay is 0](https://bugs.python.org/issue34476)). This allows another coroutine to execute up to subsequent `await`, and so on, and ends up affecting execution order in a way that is beneficial to this program. Without `asyncio.sleep(0)` the `scan_Ip`/`rl` pair never drop to the event loop and are executed in sequence, like this (simplified):

```
  1. x1 = os.popen("ping -n 1 192.168.8.0")
  2. for line in x1.readlines(): ...
  3. x2 = os.popen("ping -n 1 192.168.8.1")
  4. for line in x2.readlines(): ...
...
511. x256 = os.popen("ping -n 1 192.168.8.255")
512. for line in x256.readlines(): ...
```

Every `ping` is started, fully processed, and stopped, before another is even considered. With an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` between `os.popen()` and `readlines()`, the code is not fully async yet, but it does add a switch between the two steps, resulting in this order of execution:

```
  1. x1 = os.popen("ping -n 1 192.168.8.0")
  2. x2 = os.popen("ping -n 1 192.168.8.1")
...
256. x256 = os.popen("ping -n 1 192.168.8.255")
257. for line in x1.readlines(): ...
258. for line in x2.readlines(): ...
...
512. for line in x256.readlines(): ...
```

In other words, the same steps are executed, but reordered so that first all the commands are started, and only then are they read from. That allows the `ping` commands to produce their output (and connect to the network, etc.) all in parallel. The communication step then just picks up the output that is basically ready, lying in the pipe buffer. The fact that all `ping`s executed in parallel is what makes that version faster.

In closing, note that idiomatic asyncio code, as the one that uses `asyncio.subprocess`, doesn't require `asyncio.sleep(0)` because it already consistently awaits when waiting for data, and forcing additional sleeps would in fact make it slower.

Answer (score 2):

After running the code, it in fact does not increase runtime at all on my machine (or by only minimal times). I would assume that this is somehow triggering something similar to a ratelimit (a very short one) and having to retry sometimes, effectively doubling the runtime. Your machine might be different, but this is what I got on MacOS Catalina.

With `asyncio.sleep(0)`: 1.9657979011535645 seconds

Without `asyncio.sleep(0)`: 3.2927019596099854 seconds